Is it possible to do a background queue with single task per user without duplicates on node.js?
I'm trying to do a simple thing: allow users to upload their files, process them in a background queue and show some status.
Main problem: All users are logged in and I'd like each user to be able to only process one file at a time.
So, this means that you are upload a file, you will receive a message saying "your file is at nth place in the queue" and you will not be able to upload a new file until the last one is processed.
I have tried using BullMQ and RabbitMQ, but with any message brokers or background task libraries it is always very difficult or nearly impossible to get more control of user's task. For example to  check if a user's task is still in the queue to prevent duplication.
Is this really such a complicated thing or maybe there are some more suitable libraries for this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
